# Timer is not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to run `GetCurrentLocation()` method every 10 seconds, but the location is caught only once when the page is loaded. How can I correct it? Here is WP code:

```
 private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Callback(true);
    }
 private static Timer timer;
    private  void Main()
    {
        timer = new Timer(Callback, null, 10000, Timeout.Infinite); 
    }

    private void Callback(Object state)
    {
        GetCurrentLocation();
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The  Main method is never called.

You only call the Callback directly upon loading the page so the timer is never started.

Call Main in the Loaded handler.

Also change the `TimeOut.Infinite` to an actual number. This parameter sets the time between the ticks of the timer, not how long it will run!

Also: make the timer `private` instead of `private static`; there is no good reason to make it static as far as I can see:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StartTimer();
}

private Timer timer;

private void StartTimer()
{
    // start now and repeat every 10 seconds
    timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 10000); 
}

private void TimerCallback(Object state)
{
    GetCurrentLocation();
}
```

Comment: I added an extra tip about the interval/period between invocations. And added a suggestion on how I would code this.